# How to show different Form based on existence of Excel-File?

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015

I work in C# Visual-Studio 2015 Windows Form 
In my project I have two Windows Forms:

1. CreateDatabase-Form
2. Form1-Form

I want to achieve the following when start my application(.exe):

If the Excel-File doesn't exists I want to open CreateDatabase-Form. Otherwise I want to open the Form1-Form.

I tried the following code in the Load-Event of my program:

```
CreateDatabase frm = new CreateDatabase();  
var fileName = string.Format("{0}\\Book3105.xlsx", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());  
if (!File.Exists(fileName))  
{     
  Form1 frm1 = new Form1();  
  frm.Show();  
  frm1.Hide();              
}
else  
{             
  frm.Hide();  
  this.Show();  
}
```

Comment: I think you need another piece of code that does check that before you inizialise one of these two forms

Comment: so that what i can do for that

Comment: you would need another form/process which does the checking for you and then creates an instance of the needed Form with new.

Comment: Go through your code line by line and write down what it does.  If you do not know what it does, look up the method in the documentation.  After you have completed completed that task.  Read the steps you have written down.  Do those steps achieve your goal?  If not, revise those written down steps so that they will achieve the goal.  Then write your code to reflect those steps.

Comment: Corrected spelling and grammar. Make some formatting and restructure the question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make the check at `program.cs` and then fire `Application.Run(new Form1);` or `Application.Run(new CreateDatabase );` depending on the existance of excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Look out for "Program.cs" file in solution explorer then open it and put a check for excel file there.

Below is the code to be put in program.cs file please test it.

```
/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    var fileName = string.Format("{0}\\Book3105.xlsx", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        //Create database form when file not exist.
        Application.Run(new CreateDatabase());
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Please feel free if you have any query or issue.

Comment: @Ahmed, If you find it helpful then mark it as answer so it will help others too.